# How to correctly setup Miniflare & Miniflare Jest Testing with a Cloudflare Worker on GitHub Actions

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, github-actions, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am really struggling to correctly setup a Miniflare Enviroment with a Cloudflare Worker on GitHub Actions so I can use Miniflare Jest to perform Jest testing.

So far, I have followed the guides completely and created the deploy scrip below:

```
name: CI/CD Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 14

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Run Jest tests with Miniflare
        run: |
          npm run miniflare & 
          sleep 5
          npm test
        env:
          MINIFLARE_SCRIPT: ../src/index.js
          MINIFLARE_ADDRESS: http://127.0.0.1:8787

  production:
    needs: tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: needs.tests.result == 'success'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Publish
        uses: cloudflare/wrangler-action@2.0.0
        with:
          apiToken: ${{ secrets.CF_API_TOKEN }}
          accountId: ${{ secrets.CF_ACCOUNT_ID }}
```

I have also correctly setup Jest config with a test directory with a simple fetch test:

```
import { handleRequest } from "../src/index.js";

test("responds with url", async () => {
  const req = new Request("http://localhost/");
  const res = await handleRequest(req);
  expect(await res.text()).toBe("URL: http://localhost/ KEY: value");
});
```

This is my Jest config adding the Miniflare enviroment:

```
export default {
  testEnvironment: "miniflare",

  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    bindings: { KEY: "value" }
  },
  
  testRegex: [
    "**/tests/**/*.test.js"
  ],
};
```

However, when the actions run, under the testing stage, I receive this error:

```
Run npm run miniflare & 

> worker-typescript-template@1.0.0 miniflare /home/runner/work/edge/edge
> npx miniflare ../src/index.ts


> worker-typescript-template@1.0.0 test /home/runner/work/edge/edge
> echo 'Error: no test specified'

Error: no test specified
```

My directory has:

tests/index.test.js as the example above shows.

I have no idea why Jest isn't finding the tests I have defined.

Below is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "worker-typescript-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Cloudflare worker TypeScript template",
  "main": "dist/worker.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "wrangler dev --local",
    "build": "node build.js",
    "miniflare": "npx miniflare ../src/index.ts"
  },
  "author": "author",
  "license": "MIT OR Apache-2.0",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "extends": [
      "typescript"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cloudflare/workers-types": "latest",
    "@types/negotiator": "^0.6.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.6.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-config-typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-environment-miniflare": "^2.14.0",
    "miniflare": "^3.0.2",
    "service-worker-mock": "^2.0.5",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "wrangler": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/html-minifier": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/service-worker-mock": "^2.0.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.17.11",
    "html-minifier": "^4.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: where is your `test` script?